# Array restructure PHP

Tags: php

I am having some trouble, trying to figure out a way to restructure an array, and store it into a new one.

**This is my output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 0
            [activity] => edited
            [oid] => 62487513549577588
            [article_title] => What if Universal Solutions existed?
            [url] => http://127.0.0.1/article.php?id=62487513549577588
            [fullname] => Peter Anderson
            [photo] => http://127.0.0.1/uploads/0/147885940.png
            [link] => http://127.0.0.1/peter.anderson
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 0
            [activity] => edited
            [oid] => 776286559146635
            [article_title] => Mathematics 101: Introduction
            [url] => http://127.0.0.1/article.php?id=776286559146635
            [fullname] => Peter Anderson
            [photo] => http://127.0.0.1/uploads/0/147885940.png
            [link] => http://127.0.0.1/peter.anderson
        )

)
```

**What I desire:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => Array 
                    (
                        [user_id] => 0
                        [fullname] => Peter Anderson
                        [photo] => http://127.0.0.1/uploads/0/147885940.png
                        [link] => http://127.0.0.1/peter.anderson
                    )
            [activity] => Array
                     (
                        [activity] => edited
                     )
            [article] => Array
                  (
                    [oid] => 776286559146635
                    [url] => http://127.0.0.1/article.php?id=776286559146635
                    [article_title] => Mathematics 101: Introduction
                  ) 
        )
)
```

**This is what I've tried so far:**

```
$keys = array_keys($a); 
        for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++){
            foreach($a[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value){

                if($key == "action"){
                    $newArr[$i] = array("action" => array($key => $value));
                }
....
```

I am not of what other possibilities there are, array_map(); doesn't do what I initially thought.

Comment: Do it in a for each loop.

Comment: for-loop + foreach, don't you see above?

Comment: why are you nesting square brackets inside square brackets, and not something like [x][y]?

Comment: It's not square bracket, should I go by INDEX INDEX?

Comment: yes, that would work a lot better for nesting stuff.

Comment: Can you show me one example?

Comment: I can, but SO isn't a programming service for free.

Comment: @AjaxGuru, Sorry. It's OK. I'll try things on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `foreach` and build your final array

```
foreach($items as $item){
    $user['user_id'] = $item['user_id'];
    $user['fullname'] = $item['fullname'];
    $user['photo'] = $item['photo'];
    $user['link'] = $item['link'];

    $activity['activity'] = $item['activity'];

    $article['oid'] = $item['oid'];
    $article['url'] = $item['url'];
    $article['article_title'] = $item['article_title'];

    $result[] = array(
        'user' => $user,
        'activity' => $activity,
        'article' => $article
        );
}

print_r($result);
```

EDIT: added shorter version, without using intermediary variables

```
foreach($items as $item){
    $result[] = array(
        'user' => array(
            'user_id' => $item['user_id'],
            'fullname' => $item['fullname'],
            'photo' => $item['photo'],
            'link' => $item['link']
        ),
        'activity' => array(
            'activity' => $item['activity']
        ),
        'article' => array(
            'oid' => $item['oid'],
            'url' => $item['url'],
            'article_title' => $item['article_title']
        )
    );
}
```

Will output something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 0
                    [fullname] => Peter Anderson
                    [photo] => http://127.0.0.1/uploads/0/147885940.png
                    [link] => http://127.0.0.1/peter.anderson
                )

            [activity] => Array
                (
                    [activity] => edited
                )

            [article] => Array
                (
                    [oid] => 62487513549577588
                    [url] => http://127.0.0.1/article.php?id=62487513549577588
                    [article_title] => What if Universal Solutions existed?
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 0
                    [fullname] => Peter Anderson
                    [photo] => http://127.0.0.1/uploads/0/147885940.png
                    [link] => http://127.0.0.1/peter.anderson
                )

            [activity] => Array
                (
                    [activity] => edited
                )

            [article] => Array
                (
                    [oid] => 776286559146635
                    [url] => http://127.0.0.1/article.php?id=776286559146635
                    [article_title] => Mathematics 101: Introduction
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: WOW! You Are da KING!

Comment: Alex, is this the most optimized way? Just curious.

Comment: I guess it can be shortened a bit, but don't expect any major increases of performance. Unless you have millions of iterations in the loop this should work just fine.

Comment: Another thing before you start thinking about optimization, make sure you know **what** and **where** you optimize, so you really need to measure first and then start optimizing.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the shorter version without intermediary variables